# e2fsck - how do I restore my stuff

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, e2fsck

I have explained my situation [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1412125/1601136).

**Tl;DR** - My partitions were damaged by windows repair tool, my linux ext4 partition for my ubuntu got corrupted, I was in grub, and `ls (hd0,gpt5)/` would tell me it's `/dev/sda5` is corrupt.

I ran

```
sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda5
```

now I have a folder called `lost+found` in my partition (`/dev/sda5`). But nautilus doesn't display anything being there; I have to navigate to there using terminal.

My question is: Is there a way for me to recover my Ubuntu system back from where I am?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/9Cquzxui) are the `boot-repair-tool` diagnosis before I ran the `e2fsck` command, and remember `sda` is the SSD where I have dual boot windows and ubuntu, `sdb` and `sdc` are something else.

Comment: You need to be logged in to view this paste.

Comment: @Ned64 here -> https://pastebin.com/9Cquzxui (No login required)

Comment: Thanks for removing the password. Please note that if you ask a question here the question itself must be completely visible here without external references (one reason is that external links may change). The paste could be OK I guess since it is a long file.

Comment: for anybody reading this question - I gave up hopes for getting my ubuntu on /dev/sda5 recovered, but instead I used a tool called `ext4magic` to recover my data, I have recovered almost all the data I had in there!